# Совпадающие даты во временной шкале

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, временная-шкала

[Временная шкала для сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/602710/timeline) содержит события с одинаковой датой. При наведении мышки появляется уродский текст ["совпадающий"](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263628?key=347a1f0b662d1ab590c33a6f719b0547):

> [image: same date]

В transifex там просто одна буква `S` в оригинале. Предлагаю что-то подобное однобуквенное и оставить. Или просто вывести какую-нибудь звёздочку.

P.S. Функция отображения временной шкалы мало кому известна. Поэтому с одной стороны можно было бы и в тихую поменять перевод, но заодно захотелось дополнительно об этом функционале упомянуть, т.к. сам недавно узнал.

---

В Transifex к строке есть комментарий от Igumnov:

> Похоже эта S означает что даты совпадают(см. след строку)

Следующая строка:

> simultaneous dates
>
> совпадающие даты

Comment: P.S. `запоздавший` на `запоздалый` я уже поменял.

Comment: @NickVolynkin там достаточно на ключ посмотреть на самом деле. Следующую строку как-то неудобно крутить. Не нашел способа по порядковому номеру вывести.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать там символ `=` (равно). Чего-либо более близкого к "совпадению" в один символ я не знаю.

Comment: `=` это присваивание, надо `==`. А пэхаписты могут ещё и `===` предложить :)

Comment: @alexolut [ничего не знаю, `=` это равенство](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/=).

Comment: [Какого-то мордатого показывает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEsRn.png). Уже не показываает :(

Comment: @alexolut аргх. Символ `=` в ссылке сносит крышу некоторым браузерам, видимо. [А так?](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/%3D)

Comment: я не знаю, что было. Но сбойнуло только первый раз. Сейчас ОК.

Comment: Кстати, отличный вариант. )

Comment: Можно по юникоду ещё пройтись :)

Comment: @alexolut полный вперёд, результаты ответами :)

Comment: @D-side заодно проверим лимит кол-ва ответов на один вопрос.

Comment: дыщь-тыдыщъ `≡`

Comment: Я думал про галочку, но подозреваю, что могут быть проблемы с юникодом.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я думаю, должно быть всё ОК с юникодом.

Comment: @alexolut к сожалению, символ `≡` не для всех является символом эквивалентности / тождественности. Первая ассоциация - бутерброд, открывающий меню :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov м-м-м ... тройной воппер :-D

Comment: Применил этот вариант на transifex.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, смысл в обозначении строк с одинаковым временем. Как насчёт какого-нибудь символа, обозначающего совпадение?

Пока что поправил на "C", т.е. "совпадение".

Comment: По идее, любой, появляющийся синхронно у нескольких строк символ, будет подходящим индикатором, т.к. выводится соответствующий хинт при наведении мыши.

Comment: Кстати, а как у Вас отображается блок с суточным голосованием? Там есть имена участников или тоже N/A?

Comment: @alexolut там сумма голосов за день только

Comment: в поле "кем"? Это довольно странно.

Comment: @alexolut отвечал по памяти и с телефона. Проверил — да, там "N/A"

Comment: Пора значит памяти в телефон добавить :)